# Is there an active Mod for this Stack?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Looks like the single *pro tem* mod hasn't been active for over a year, and it seems to me that DonQuiKong, Eric Shain and Maca are doing the actual mod work on this forum.

Possibly it's time to formalize and appoint new *pro tem* mods?

Answer (score 1):

This site does not function like any other Stack Exchange site. It was created without the process we typically use to make sure it has a sufficient community to support it. When that didn't work out, I was asked to unilaterally maintain this site absent any significant community *self-* moderation. Everyone we have enlisted to operate this site is long gone, so I will not likely be appointing additional Moderators here anytime soon. I go into this more here:

[Decision what's on/off-topic by moderator](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/a/352/1)

I can understand the frustration when folks expect this to work like any other Stack Exchange site. It's a contentious issue every time it comes up. Even if the users you listed agreed to step up, the future of this site is uncertain. Realistically I don't want to start enlisting folks for Moderator positions when the fundamental problems with this site remain unaddressed, and there is no watchful community to balance out and support those roles.

Comment: My only comment would be that Patents potentially adds a great deal of value to Stack overall, even if perennially underutilized, because patents are an important aspect of technology, and distinct from other areas of IP Law, and Law in general.  It's useful to have a place to discuss algorithmic and other types of patents on a tech and science forum.

Comment: Additionally, as the three users I mentioned are already doing the work, I can't see how it constitutes devoting additional resources...

Comment: @DukeZhou Yes; it should have been define by a community based out of need, and gone through the site-creation process to rally a community who will actually vet and support it.

Comment: Feels like getting technical over rules, as opposed to looking at the utility which it provides, however limited.  Isn't the purpose of SE to be useful?  Isn't the purpose of the expanded Stack community also partly to raise the rankings of Stack in general, and continue to ensure it comes up high in the google search rankings?  Every little bit helps. :)

Comment: @DukeZhou You're marginalizing the community needed to make these sites work. If the bar is simply to create more sites, I can have 1,000 created by tomorrow.

Comment: We're providing useful, correct information on this Stack and helping people get answers to basic questions.  Don is studying to become a patent attorney and knows the European laws, Eric has many dozens of successful patents under his belt, Maca is extremely knowledgable, and as for myself, my focus is on game patents, which is an historically important niche.  We're linking people to government statutes online, breaking down published patents, and linking to review articles that help people understand how to navigate the landscape.  Few active users, but high value.

Comment: I'm also uncomfortable that the only active person with Mod authority on this stack is actively seeking to shut it down, despite the consistent efforts of the small group of expert contributors.

Answer (score 1):

What I'm doing doesn't need mod power and I do agree with Robert that this site needs some kind of rework. He does most of the necessary mod work and I mostly agree with his actions.

I don't see many unsolved jobs for a mod here, so I don't think another one is needed. I don't know how much the other pro tem mod does as hidden work, but I've seen it occasionally, especially when looking for his actions, so I suspect it's *more than you think*.

I've realised that the occasional spam question which doesn't get fast flags or mod attention can be solved by bringing it up in the main meta chat.

This site allows us to participate and has the necessary moderation. Other than taking some work away from Robert, I don't see a reason for a new mod unless the site grows a good bit.